# Calling the parent class' __init__ right away when subclassing

Tags: python

I was reading the answers to [Usage of __slots__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots) and I noticed that one of the examples is :

```
from collections import namedtuple
class MyNT(namedtuple('MyNT', 'bar baz')):
    """MyNT is an immutable and lightweight object"""
    __slots__ = ()
```

I saw that the `__init__` of `namedtuple` was called when it was being subclassed by `MyNT`

I went ahead and tested it for myself and made this code which is my first attempt to understand such behavior:

```
class objectP():
    def __init__(self,name):
            print('object P inited')

class p(objectP('asd')):
    pass
```

I got an error stating that `4` objects were "passed" so I changed it to

```
class objectP():
    def __init__(self,*a):
            print('object P inited')

class p(objectP('asd')):
    pass
```

which now produces an output of

```
object P inited
object P inited
```

1. What does the line of code above mean? Calling `__init__` when subclassing?
2. Why is `object P inited` printed twice?

Comment: `namedtuple('MyNT', 'bar baz')` returns a *class*, an instance of `type` not of `object`. If you want `p` to inherit from `objectP(...)`, then `objectP` should inherit from `type` not `object`. `namedtuple` itself is a function, not a class - see [the source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l356). There's no `__init__` being called there.

Comment: Further to the above, a class inheriting from `type` is usually referred to as a [*"metaclass"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/3001761), and is a whole rabbit hole you almost certainly don't need to be going down!

Comment: Ohhh alright thank you!

Comment: Wait... you can inherit from an instance?!

Comment: @JaredGoguen: If the instance is an instance of `type`, sure. Every class is an instance already!

Answer (score 0):

The example code you list at the top of your question works because the `namedtuple` function (which isn't actually a class itself) *returns* a class. You're inheriting from that returned class, not from `namedtuple` itself.

The same structure doesn't work when you use it in your other code because calling the `ObjectP` class returns an instance when you call it, and that instance isn't a class that can be inherited from.

You *can* write a function that returns a class, like `namedtuple` does. You can also write a class who's instances are other classes. That's called a "metatype" and in Python 3 metatypes need to inherit from the `type` class.

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        print("creating a new type named", name)
        return super().__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)

class MyClass1(MyMeta("Base", (), {})): # you can inherit from an instance
    pass

class MyClass2(metaclass=MyMeta): # or use the special metaclass syntax
    pass
```

While metaclasses are neat, they can be a bit confusing if you're new to them. It gets a bit metaphysical, with `type` being an instance of itself (and a subclass of `object` for good measure). This stuff is the magical core of Python's type system, and you don't really need to understand it to use classes in ordinary ways.